# Where does jquery's getscript() function look when called in an external file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, getscript, file-structure

If i have a file system like:

```
project -> public -> js -> myfile.js
```

If i call getScript() in myfile.js where does it look at first? Is this generally true for other things?

For example if I call getScript("myotherfile.js") and myotherfile.js is in the js folder would that be sufficient to access myotherfile.js?

Does the getscript call from my html document or myfile.js?

Answer (score 3):

the path will be taken from the url which is appearing in the browser.

ie)

if the site url is `example.com/test1/test2/` and the call is made from this page and if you are mentioning `/` infront of the js file url then the end result will be like `example.com/myotherfile.js`. if you are not putting any slash then it will refer like `example.com/test1/test2/myotherfile.js`.

NOTE: i am not sure if i got your question right.

for more info please read on `absolute paths` and `relative paths`

[**LINK**](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/) for reference

Comment: Agreed. It has nothing to do with the filesystem structure; it's all relative to the URL structure.